# How do I know if my SSD is damaged?

Tags: ssd, dd

When I use 'dd' to make an image of my sad, I get the message:

```
dd: /dev/disk1: Input/output error
```

I've tried on Mac and Ubuntu (the Mac output is above) and the result is the same. My question is: what is wrong with my one week old SDHC card (Kingston Class 4, 8GB)? And more importantly, what tools (preferably GUI) exist on Ubuntu to analyse and fix this problem?

Answer (score 1):

Try this.  check the file system for bad sectors, just press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> on your keyboard to open Terminal. When it opens, run the command(s) below:

```
sudo fsck -a /dev/disk1
```

Depending on the exit code, you can try reformatting the card, and see it helps.  For more info look at [fsck man page](http://linux.die.net/man/8/fsck).

Comment: Hi Mitch. I've tried reformatting but no joy. There are FAT32 as well as ext partitions on the disk (it's a raspberry pi image). I've used Disk Utility to delete the partitions and format the disk as both FAT32 and again as ext4 but dd fails with the same error. Does this indicate that the issue isn't just logical/filesystem but perhaps a physical defect?